# Usercontrol with a Dependency Property doesn't recognise changes

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom class which a usercontrol has implemented as a dependency property in it's code behind.

```
public partial class HandControl
{
    public HandControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Seat Seat
    {
        get
        {
            return (Seat)GetValue(SeatProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SeatProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Seat", typeof(Seat), typeof(HandControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

In my case I've bound the name property in that class to a label inside the usercontrols xaml.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Seat.Player.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:HandControl}}}"/>
```

The view model of my window contains the property SeatTl and the xaml is binding to it:

```
    public Seat SeatTr
    {
        get { return _seatTr; }
        private set
        {
            _seatTr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    <customControls:HandControl Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                Seat="{Binding SeatTr}" />
```

However, when I change my class content (the name property) and manually raise OnPropertyChanged in my viewmodel (not the usercontrol), the label is not updated and still has the same content.

```
    private void OnSeatChanged(Player player, SeatPosition seatPosition)
    {
        //... doing the changes ...\\
        OnPropertyChanged("SeatTr");
    }
```

Whats my problem? Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u should raise  OnPropertyChanged for Seat.Player.Name property as It is being chaged.

Comment: Exactly, that was my problem. I had to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged into my Seat Class aswell.